# Subset whole nested dataframe structure R

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

I have a dataset with nested structures in R (some cells are arrays from its original JSON structure).

```
set.seed(123)
data = list()
data$nested_df_1 = data.frame(a = letters[1:10]
                              , b = round(rnorm(10), 0))
data$nested_df_2 = list()
data$nested_df_2$nested_df_2_1 = data.frame(c = letters[11:20]
                                            , d = sample(-100:100, 10))
```

Now I want to subset the whole list `data` so that it only includes all instances (= all rows in all structures) where `data$nested_df_1$b >= 0`.

```
> data$nested_df_1
   a  b
1  a -1
2  b  0
3  c  2
4  d  0
5  e  0
6  f  2
7  g  0
8  h -1
9  i -1
10 j  0
```

Thus: rows 1, 8, 9 would need to be removed from the whole structure (i.e. from `data$nested_df_1` and `data$nested_df_2$nested_df_2_1`.

If I just wanted this for the `data$nested_df_1` dataframe, I could do:

```
data$nested_df_1 = data$nested_df_1[data$nested_df_1$b >= 0, ]
```

(The indices remain constant, i.e. if `row_i` in `data$nested_df_1` meets the criterion, then this is also true for `row_i` in `data$nested_df_2$nested_df_2_1`).

But how can I do the subset for the whole nested structure?

Comment: Can you show the expeected output

Comment: Perhaps `i1 <- data$nested_df_1$b >= 0;  lapply(data, function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) subset(x, i1) else lapply(x, function(y) subset(y, i1)))`

Comment: Thanks - happy to take this as an answer if you want to post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a logical index, loop through the `list`, if it is a `data.frame` `subset` or else loop through the `list` and `subset` (assuming `list` nest is of depth 2)

```
i1 <- data$nested_df_1$b >= 0
lapply(data, function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)) subset(x, i1) else
        lapply(x, function(y) subset(y, i1)))
```